# Measuring Current in a PWM circuit

Tags: pwm, current-measurement

I am working on a simple project that entails controlling the power to a heating strip to control its temperature. The heating strip is not much more than a resistor with resistance provided by chromium wires. I think a simple potentiometer can work to adjust the current in the 12 V circuit, but I am trying to use a [dimmer switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01C4UBMY6) that happens to be PWM for all good reasons. I haven't been able to examine the current through the circuit in part because the switch is kind of weird - with just three wires, and in part maybe something is wrong with the switch. But I have also wondered if the current in a PWM circuit can be measured using conventional multimeter devices.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a "true-RMS" meter you can measure the RMS current directly.

If you have an averaging meter, your meter will measure (not surprisingly) the average current, which is a real measurement but does not accurately represent the heating effect.

For a duty cycle of 0 \$\le \alpha \le \$ 1 you will get a reading RD= \$ \alpha I_{MAX}\$ where Imax is the current at 100% duty cycle.

We know that the *power* is actually \$ \alpha P_{MAX}\$ so the RMS current (for constant resistance) must be \$I_{RMS} = \sqrt{RD\cdot I_{MAX}}\$

So, for example, if you average-reading meter shows a 5A reading for a maximum current of 10A at 100% duty cycle, then the RMS current (assuming constant resistance load) is 7.1A.

Comment: Okay, sounds good. It is my first time working with a PWM switch (dimmer) for a device and I didn't know if measuring current, regardless of its intensity, is the same as when measuring current on any circuit. Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 1):

I would measure the current at 100% PWM duty (DC). And then delivered power is equivalent to the PWM duty at the moment. Meantime, the current may decrease upon increasing temperature due to the positive temperature coefficient of the heating element.

PWM duty can be measured by reading the voltage (DC average).

Comment: I am okay with measuring current at 100%, and my goal was just to see that the PWM dimmer actually causes change in current when I use it. I am not able to do that, and so I wanted to know if a special method is needed for PWM systems. Apparently there isn't, and I need to figure out why I cannot measure ay current. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Farzad, Have you tried measuring DC current of that PWM system you have, if you can? If you were using an Ammeter, you may likely see the average DC current. Using DMM will depend on the PWM frequency and the DMM. Some DMMs use "dual slop" ADC to filter out the line frequency, and will be able to see the average DC current, if the PWM frequency is high enough.

Comment: Jay, I have tried, and could not get any reading. I have trashed my multimeter and am looking to get another one because it looks like my MM was not working properly. I have created a circuit with a PWM dimmer switch and a100 ohm resistor and used another meter and i am getting linear current response in the circuit. I say linear because the current goes up as I turn the knob - Thanks.

Comment: @Farzad, that sounds right! I could not add that in my answer, because the result depends on many factors. Though, I would do that for my own tests as well. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For thermal time delay reasons, you don't need very fast PWM even 1Hz is fast with enough mass and insulation.

With a low pass filter, now it's easy to measure current.  The thermistor feedback used for control will keep it regulated with 0.1'C if you want but where you sense temp is more important for errors.

Measuring power with PWM would use a Low Pass RC filter to measure fast duty cycle using Vdc. Then estimate the hot resistance load or measure it on DC with Amps.

Comment: Sorry, but what is Low Pass RC filter? I am measuring current delivered to an analog resistor-type device and I am using a dimmer to control the voltage therefore the current. The dimmer is a PMD dimmer. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I suggest a thermostat method of heater , like from a baseboard heater with a sensor.  But if you use that dimmer , you can measure average DC voltage of an AC PWM output using for example a series resistor (100k) to a parallel cap across the DC meter (0.1uF) .  This is an RC Low Pass Filter LPF

Comment: To measure DC+AC current accurately here you can try setting for DC 10A but don't blow the fuse, it may not be accurate .

Comment: Well, it turns out my multimeter's current measuring service is defective. I was able to get current reading using another meter. Thanks for the input.